# str_replace and Replace is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Want to execute this query but it doesn't print anything because of str_replace,I also used Replace in place of str_replace but it doesn't work for me.Where

`$name = iFLY-San-Diego-Kids-Club`

In database--
its like `iFLY San Diego Kids Club`

please help anyone to get this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
   $rs = $this->db->select('*')                                                                                                           
          ->from('table')
          ->where('table.status', 'Active')
          ->where('table.id', $id)
          ->where('table.title', str_replace('-',' ',$name))
          ->get()->result();
}
```

Comment: Try doing a print of just the str replace and check what it prints

Answer (score 5):

Your query is perfect but instead of `where` you can use `like` clause like mentioned below.

```
->where('table.title', str_replace('-',' ',$name))
```

**Replace with**

```
->like('table.title', str_replace('-',' ',$name))
```

If you use `like` then it will automatically add  wildcard(`%`) in your query.

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: @user6891871 : Glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like

```
$newname = str_replace("-","",$name); 

$rs = $this->db->select('*')                                                                                                           
          ->from('table')
          ->where('table.status', 'Active')
          ->where('table.id', $id)
          ->where('table.title', $newname)
          ->get()->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `str_replace('-',' ',$name)` try `str_replace('-','_',$name)`